# how can I get a field value in 3 association tables with the max of date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, having

So, I have a table and I want to get the value from one field in the record with the greatest `DateTime()` value in another field and where still another field is equal to a certain value.

```
    --
    -- Structure de la table `site`
    --
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `site_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `address` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
      `entity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status_activity` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `infra` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `idx_site_name` (`site_name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

    --
    -- Contenu de la table `site`
    --

    INSERT INTO `site` (`id`, `site_name`, `city`, `address`, `entity`, `status_activity`, `infra`) VALUES
    (1, 'FR001', 'tttt', 'tttttttttt', 'yyyyy', 1, 0),
    (2, 'FR002', 'ccccc', 'cccccccccc', 'rrrrrrrrrrrr', 1, 0);

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Structure de la table `site_topology`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_topology` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id_site` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `id_topology` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `date` date NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `idx_site_date` (`date`),
      KEY `fk_id_site_2` (`id_site`),
      KEY `fk_id_topology_2` (`id_topology`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

    --
    -- Contenu de la table `site_topology`
    --

    INSERT INTO `site_topology` (`id`, `id_site`, `id_topology`, `date`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, '2015-03-03'),
    (2, 2, 3, '2015-03-03'),
    (3, 1, 2, '2015-04-30'),
    (4, 2, 5, '2015-04-30'),
    (5, 1, 1, '2015-06-25'),
    (6, 2, 4, '2015-06-25');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Structure de la table `topology`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topology` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `idx_type_name` (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

    --
    -- Contenu de la table `topology`
    --

    INSERT INTO `topology` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (3, 'C1/C2'),
    (2, 'C3'),
    (5, 'HBN'),
    (4, 'Infrastruc'),
    (6, 'LB'),
    (1, 'SHBN');

    --
    -- Contraintes pour les tables exportées
    --

    --
    -- Contraintes pour la table `site_topology`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `site_topology`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_site_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_site`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id_topology_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_topology`) REFERENCES `topology` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I want to see

```
FR001 SHBN 2015-06-26
FR002 Infrastruct 2015-06-26
```

but when I execute my query I have this

```
FR001 SHBN 2015-06-26`enter code here`
FR002 C1/C2 2015-06-26
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have a lot of information here as far as table creation and test data. That could just as well be in a SQL Fiddle session, but that's a small detail. But when you describe what you are looking for, you say, "...the value from one field in the record with the greatest DateTime() value in another field and where still another field is equal to a certain value." Is it possible to be more vague? And you show the result of your query but you don't show the query. I, for one, have no idea what you want or what your problem may be.

Answer (score 1):

You had a problem on how to choose the max date, since the month was showing first. A different way is to **bring up the max_date value** (from a sub-query). After it you can **compare by the different parts of the date**. Code as follows:

```
select site_name, site_date, name 
 from
  (
    select  site_name, st.date as site_date, name, s.id, (select max(sto.date) from site_topology sto) as max_date
    from site s 
     inner join site_topology st on s.id =st.id_site
     inner join topology t on st.id_topology = t.id 
  )  as v
 where YEAR(site_date) = YEAR(max_date) AND MONTH(site_date) = MONTH(max_date) AND DAY(site_date) = DAY(max_date)
 group by name
 order by site_name
```

[Testing here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64521/94).

Comment: [@chall](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4554014/chall) have you tried it? As far as I know it should work!

Comment: It's a possibility to have the max(date) inside the sub-select, but have you tested to up the max in the main WHERE, like: "where xxxx in (select max(date).....)"

Comment: That would produce even cleaner code! Thanks @Jabuciervo

Answer (score 0):

use a subquery they're correct's aggregate [Results here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64521/9/0)

```
select site_name,max(date), name 
   from
    (select  site_name, 
     city, address, entity , status_activity, infra,
     st.*,name
     from site s 
       inner join site_topology st on s.id =st.id_site
       inner join topology t on st.id_topology = t.id ) 
     as v
   group by site_name
```

Comment: thx, but it is give me the same result
FR001 SHBN 2015-06-25
FR002  C1/C2 2015-06-25
but i want like that
FR001 SHBN 2015-06-25
FR002  Infrastruct 2015-06-25