# Comparing two date columns and adding derived column using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My table structure is this:

```
ID,
country,
month,
year,
total amt in previous period,
total amt during period,
incr/decr in total amt in previous period,
incr/decr in total amt during (month, year)
```

The `ID`, `month`, `year` and `total amt` fields are available in table `abc`.
The `incr/decr in total amt in previous period` is the difference between `total amt in previous period` and `total amt during period` columns.

I wrote this query:

```
select m.id, m.month, m.year, m.total_amt 
from abc m    
order by year, month desc;
```

For the `total amt in previous period` I could not use `Between Date( ) And DateAdd("M", -1, Date( ));` as I have no date but just year and month.

How to compare the two columns with the columns `year` and `month` and how to have the last two derived columns using subqueries?

Comment: You're table structure is not clear for me.

Comment: the total amt during period compares to month and year and returns values from " total amt" in current month and year (march 2015) and total amt in previous period compares to the previous month (feb 2015) of the current month and displays values

Answer (score 1):

For comparing Month there is an specific function (that works for MS SQL and ORACLE). There's one function for days and years too. See links below:

[YEAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)

[MONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

[DAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx)

Examples of this and getting derived columns from subqueries can be found in this topic already discussed in the forum:

[Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297793/how-i-can-get-a-field-value-in-3-association-tables-with-the-max-of-date/29300149#29300149)

Comment: Hi, I'm generating reports using oracle reports builder for which I need sql query but I think it accepts single query and hence I'm in need for a lil help, thank you

Comment: I've checked and its the same function for Oracle: [MONTH FUNCTION](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefmonthfunc.html)
So you can use the examples I've sent to you. If any other question, please ask.